# Am I a baritone or a tenor based on these points?

Tags: voice

I am a 15 year old male that is confused about whether I am a baritone or a tenor. My lowest note that I can hit(barely audible) is a G2 and my highest note is a E4 or F4 in full chest and straining while in F4, if im not using enough pressure, it flips into falsetto frequently. I kinda confused about primo and secondo passaggio points so Im just gonna use the zona di passaggio(which is the part where it flips into falsetto uncontrollably) is E4/F4. I dont really know about the timbre so I guess we cant talk about that XD. 
Ps. Can smb tell me how to use my mix too?

Comment: I don't know whether it would help or whether you have the means to do this, but is it possible to have a link or an example of your vocal performance to work from?

Comment: To be honest, you might not be able to answer those questions in the next 5 years, and maybe not in the next 10. An  "average" 15-year-old might not have the same "voice" for two days running. Just keep singing, but don't force or strain your voice to do anything, and you will find out eventually. You can't speed up your physiological development by worrying about it.

Comment: Check out that question and the questions linked in my comment on it.  If you have any more specific questions after reading the answers, please feel free to make another post about them!